# Find TXT files and show Total Count of records of each file and Size of each file

Tags: shell

I need to find row Count and size of each TXT files.

It needs to search all the directories and just show result as  :

```
FileName|Cnt|Size

ABC.TXT|230|23MB
```

Here is some code:

```
v_DIR=$1
echo "the directory to cd is "$1


x=`ls -l $0 | awk '{print $9 "|" $5}'`
y=`awk 'END {print NR}' $0`
echo $x '|' $y
```

Comment: what about `wc -l filename` ? Good luck.

Comment: i am trying to create Sh script , the command above is only outputting : test.sh|139 | 9      Looks like i need to use For Loops.. and i want only the look for TXT files . Can you help ?

Comment: `wc -l *.TXT` ? It's still now clear what you're expected output should look like. Instead of trying to verbally describe our output, please edit your question to include an exact sample of your required output, given a known input. If you need `|` delimited data, better to filter the output of `wc` to provide that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

> find -type f -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'lines=$(wc -l "$0" | cut -d " " -f1); size=$(du -h "$0" | cut -f1); echo "$0|$lines|$size"' {} \;

Comment: +1. I'd suggest quoting `"{}"` in case the filename contains spaces.

Comment: You'll need a directory from which to begin finding after the `find`, eg: `find /tmp -type f...`.

Comment: @bishop Not for gnu find, which assumes current working directory if none listed.

Comment: @glennjackman I've heard that before, but haven't actually seen any problems with it. Might depend on find version as to when `{}` actually gets replaced.

Comment: @BroSlow, it's not find that will be bothered: by using quotes, you're ensuring the bash script receives the entire filename into `$0`

Comment: @glennjackman Right, but `find` replaces `{}` at some point when processing -exec. Could look at the code, but my guess is it's later rather than earlier (e.g. it handling replacing `$0` rather than letting the shell take it) since this works with spaces on my system.

Comment: Just tested it, and you're right, omitting the quotes does not break filenames with spaces.

Comment: @BroSlow: Cool, didn't know that about GNU `find`!